# Func<int,bool> without return keyword in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

While using Linq I stumbled upon the following expression:

```
bool biggerThan10Exists = numbers.Any(n => n > 10);
```

The definition for Any is as follows:

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate
)
```

The definition for Func is as follows:

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(
        T arg
)
```

So if **Any** requires a **Func** which requires delegates to be passed that **returns** an int, how comes I can pass a lambda expression that in my opinion is a definition of a **void** delegate, i.e.

```
n => n > 10
```

While I would expect

```
n => return n > 10
```

I'm pretty sure I'm obviously missing something here, but what?

Comment: The "return" is implied when what follows `=>` is an expression. In fact, originally you could not legally use `return` in the body of a lambda at all.

Comment: The return statement is not the only thing that is implied; almost everything is. The only things not implied are the parameter name and the method body. This video explains it really well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KRjeu9Thp3s&list=PLAE7FECFFFCBE1A54&index=5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This type of lambda expression is called an *expression lambda*:

```
n => n > 10
```

In expression lambdas, what follows `=>` must be an expression and the return type is inferred by the compiler. One of the consequences is that you cannot use expression lambda syntax to create a lambda with a `void` return type.

There is another syntax for lambdas, called *statement lambda*:

```
n => { return n > 10; }
```

Here the `=>` is followed by a block containing one or more statements; if you want to return a value you must do so explicitly, and it's also possible to have a `void` return type (don't return anything).

Note that support for statement lambdas was only added in .NET 4.0, and in general is worse throughout the framework than that for expression lambdas, e.g. many (all?) LINQ query providers will refuse to work with statement lambdas even if they can be trivially written as the equivalent expression lambda.

Comment: Unfortunately, when trying n => { return n > 10; }, I get "A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree". I guess that's because Any really requires "expressions" instead of statement blocks, but I can't quite see the reason why this limitation is there.

Comment: @user1610325: There is no technical reason why this particular lambda could not work, but the compiler has a blanket limitation -- it won't create expression trees from statement lambdas, even in the most trivial cases (although you can create them manually of course). This is really as it should be because in the general case you can't convert statements to expressions.

Answer (score 4):

`n > 10` is an expression that returns a *boolean* value.

So `n => n > 10` means, take `n` and return true if it's bigger than 10, return false otherwise...

Also here the return is implicit. You can also write it like this:

```
n => { return n > 10; }
```

This is simply equivelant to:

```
n => {   
         if (n > 10) 
              return true;
          return false;
     };
```